# print double with digits after decimal point

Tags: c#, .net

How can I customize a function in which I print doubles? I would like this function to get number of digits after the decimal point (comma in my locale) as an agrument and then print, for example, pi with the number of digits after comma specified by user.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var digits = 4;
var myDouble = Math.PI;

var formattedValue = myDouble.ToString("N" + digits.ToString(),
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture -> this isnt necessary

Comment: @gruber - I include the culture specification out of habit because Code Analysis/FxCop barks at you if you don't. Regardless, I am glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) might help you out using the [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits.aspx) property.

Code example from MS.

```
Public Shared Sub Main()

  //' Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
  Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US", False).NumberFormat

  //' Displays a negative value with the default number of decimal digits (2).
  Dim myInt As Int64 = - 1234
  Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi))

  //' Displays the same value with four decimal digits.
  nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 4
  Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi))

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I am telling you in a way, that i solved a similar problem in my project.

Convert the resulting value to a string. Since you use like pi = 3,14

```
String Result = "3,14";
```

using

> Split(Char()) //use a comma to split this into array

You will get a array now, array[1] will give you the second part.

Since its still a string, use `string.Length()` function to get the Length, (nothing but the number of digits that comes after the comma).

You can now print the resulting digits in whichever way you want