# Display double as its true value?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double in C# like below:
`var myDouble = 1.0;`

When I want to display this double, it prints as `1` when it should print as `1.0`, I'm using this for a version so it kind of defeats the object.

How can I display it as its true value? 1.0 not 1...

Comment: Try "ToString("0.0");  - formatting command

Comment: How do you define it's true value? Would you expect it to print 1.00 if you had `var myDouble = 1.00;`?

Comment: printing where? how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print double with digits after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381829/print-double-with-digits-after-decimal-point)

Comment: If you're storing a version then .NET's [`Version` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version) would likely serve you better.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var myDouble = 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString("0.0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This question does not technically have an answer.  The double is a 64-bit (and float as 32-bit) numeric floating point type.  There's fundamentally no distinction between 1, 1.0, 1.00 and 1.000.  These are all the SAME value.

In fact, that binary value if its 64-bit comes out to 3FF0000000000000 for ALL those examples.  If its 32-bit, the binary expression is different but the idea is the same.

The format is defined by IEE 754 specification.  More information on that is here:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

There are 3 sections if a floating point number:
1.  Sign Bit
2.  Exponent
3.  Mantissa

There's no section for "number of zeros I typed".

Basically though, once you convert it to a number, you have lost the definition of how you had formatted the text, that just doesn't exist for a number.

If you want to remember how many decimal places you typed, you need to store it as a string.  If you just want to format the decimal data type, you need to specify a format as there's no knowledge of your original format.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as correct to say that "1" is its *true* value.

You can format the number as you want using something like this:

```
myDouble.ToString("0.0");
```

But I really don't understand why you would. A version is generally formatted a specific way. Some people format it as "1.00". I really think it makes more sense to store it in a string so it is always guaranteed to appear exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable in double type like this:

```
double a = 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.0}",a));
```